# Programming a PIC with a programmer on demo board

Tags: pic, programmer, board

I'm a beginner on PIC world. I'm doing a project with PIC PIC18F04Q40 and I'm curious if I can use the programmer/debugger present in a Curiosity HPC board to program the PIC18F04Q40 through ICSP programming, soldering the pins PGD, PCG, MCLR and VDD present on curiosity board to my custom board.

Comment: Yes, that should work just fine. Just don't forget to connect GND as well, which you didn't mention.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mention GND because I know that I have also to connect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should work just fine.

The programmer/debugger on the Curiosity HPC board is a *PICKit On-Board 3* (PKOB), which has about the same capabilities as a regular PICKit 3.
Only major difference that I am aware of, is the lack of high-voltage programming capability in the PKOB. But as long as LVP is not disabled in the target MCU, LVP usually works fine.

Just don't forget to connect GND as well, which you didn't mention.